# Java ResultSet giving returning wrong values for some columns

Tags: java, multithreading, oracle, resultset

I have an applicaton that executes a query using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate. The resultSet is then parsed row by row using ResultSet.next().

Now in some cases during multi threading scenarios, this goes wrong. The result set is returning wrong values. When I execute the same query in SQLDeveloper, I am seeing the correct values. Not sure what could be the problem behind this.

```
while (rs.next()) {
  count++;
  long dbKy = rs.getLong("DBKY");
  pAttrs = map.get(dbKy );
  if (pAttrs== null) {
    pAttrs= new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put(dbKy , pAttrs);
  }
  log.info( "PrintingResultSet!!::"+rs.getLong("DBKY")
           +"::"+rs.getString(ATTR_NAME)
           +"::"+rs.getString(ATTR_VAL)
           +"::"+rs.getString(Constants.VAL));
  pAttrs.put(rs.getString(ATTR_NAME),rs.getString(ATTR_VAL));
}
```

EDIT: This code is in the repo layer of SpringBoot application. Multithreading is, this issue happens when multiple requests are sent simultaneously. I have printed Thread id in my logs and it confirms that this happens only in multi threaded scenarios.

The value that is being returned actually is the value of some other row.

Comment: What/how is your multi threading scenarios ?

Comment: Could you brief your scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

What values (wrong values) do you see when you are trying to display the resultset. If you see some unknown texts or symbols then probably it could be "*encoding*" issue. I suggest you to please refer on how to encode values like some special characters/symbols on your service layer since no doubt you will be able to see the data in the database by using the query but if that data contains some special characters/symbols then there  is a need of encoding "UTF-8".

**Thanks!**

Comment: Hi @Ashraf. Thanks for you comments. No its not about unknown texts. I am seeing the values that should have been in the other rows.

Comment: In your connection to Oracle, set try setting "threaded=true". For example, dbconn = cx_Oracle.connect('usr', 'pswd', myhost,threaded=True)